Chrome crashes without any errors when I open a web page made with web components
Chrome crashes when I open a webpage written with Web Components.
It started happening with version 128.0.6613.113. I have the latest version installed:
128.0.6613.120, even with this version chrome crashes.
It is very strange as there are no logs in the console. I have tried quantifying the memory while opening this webpage, nothing too crazy in terms if memory.
Once it crashes, I am unable to inspect or reload the webpage.
This application is a private network application.
Here is the tech stack I am using:

Java
Kotlin (For backend)
JavaScript
TypeScript
Lit-elements
Web components
Cloudfoundry


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

We are seeing something similar. Can it be related to window.open from javacript? In our environment we have registered a custom protocol handler, and when trying to open that from javascript using window.open, the browser crashes.

Yes, If I use window.open('/foo/bar', '_self'); it works (not always though)

I think it is related to this bug:
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/292536913/crash-on-calling-custom-protocol-handler-chrome-dynamicsnav-in-new-version-128-0-6613-85?hl=en

Thanks for sharing. Were you able to find out any concrete workaround for this?

@AahladKethineedi - yes. We replaced windows.open() with a solution that used an iframe to open the url. You can also use windows open with a popup, but that is not pretty.

Update: With latest chrome version(128.0.6613.138) this issue has been fixed.
